# function expression: after after the trailing comma:

Tags: javascript

what is this after the comma for the expression means? I am not understanding. Thanks all.

```
const appearOptions = {
                    root: null,
                    rootMargin: "0px 0px -50px 0px",
                    threshold: 0
                };

                const appearOnScroll = new IntersectionObserver(function (entries) {
                    entries.forEach(entry => {
                        if (!entry.isIntersecting) {
                            console.log(entry.target)
                            entry.target.classList.remove("active");
                        } else {
                            entry.target.classList.add("active");
                            // console.log(entry.target);
                        }
                    });
                },
                appearOptions);
```

Comment: format the code please.

Comment: Are you talking about `appearOptions`? That is just the object containing the options passed to the IntersectionObserver constructor as second argument, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver/IntersectionObserver#syntax

Answer (score 1):

It's the second parameter for the `IntersectionObserver` constructor